# Hiding notification about my post, published on other's Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I think it will be better if I explain my problem by example.

We have given two Facebook profiles: A and B. A is our profile and B is e.g public fan page profile with public visibility.

1. Person A publishes post on B's wall.
2. Now person B writes a comment under person A's post.
3. Person B gives a "like" on A's post (wrote on his own wall)

Do friends of A person receive notification about A's activity in their news feed in cases: 1, 2, 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Friends of A **may** see A's activity in their news feeds in case 1.
2. Subscribers of B who also posted on A's post on B's wall **may** also see B's activity in their news feeds in case 2.
3. Subscribers of B **may** see B's activity in their news feeds in case 3.

Note that I use the word "may" because Facebook chooses what is relevant to show in News Feeds per user, based on each user's number of friends/subscriptions/specialize lists, the popularity of the post, etc. In any case, everything you can see should always show up in the news ticker, which takes more of a "fire hose" approach to showing updates, whereas the news feed attempts to show you only the most relevant news.

You can also read my earlier answers on visibility [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29225/if-joe-likes-my-facebook-status-update-will-joes-friends-see-my-update/29426#29426) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39823/facebook-which-of-my-actions-are-reported-to-friends-etc/39908#39908).